# Is there a list of OpenGL extension support?

Tags: opengl

I am looking for a list that states which vendor does support which OpenGL extension.

For example I wanted to use `ARB_shading_language_include`, which was accepted in 2013, but from various forums on the internet I assume it isn't implemented on AMD drivers. But I can't find any official document that states where this extension is supported.

Does such a list exist?

Comment: There is no "official document", but there is a [public OpenGL database that stores this kind of thing from numerous implementations](http://opengl.gpuinfo.org/).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no general document for extensions support, though some databases are kept largely up to date by communities:

https://opengl.gpuinfo.org/listreports.php?extension=GL_ARB_shading_language_include

As of writing no AMD renderers show up as supporting `ARB_shading_language_include`.